# Гугл говорит о наличии вирусов

Tags: вирусы

Проверил сайт на наличие вирусов через сервис Ai-Bolit он сказал чтовсе чисто, хотсер так-же не видит ничего вредного, а вот гугл упорно говорит что на сайте беда)))

> Последняя проверка сайта 05.09.2018 : `http://autoplaz.com.ua` показала, что на Вашем сайте присутствуют следующие вредоносные ссылки:
>
> http://centersmobileappss.com/?url=3a4eNNytBYMVLIeC2UkdQxP8RL6FholDqCSlxrf%2Fk1yBfQM9anRX5kAQKnZDXRn4%2F8hLOTqBE0R8OuvLHqs%2Fap%2FE%2Fe5oZdphOzUirH74SfMUQHpNCTImDoUGA6vqElNK, http://centersmobileappss.com/away.php, http://game5223.check-jacksmoney84.loan/?utm_medium=NQ3aDvyuBCtafRQJPeFC66tm%2BMNW8T%2BaflxP0d0AJGo%3D&t=main7_6, http://game5223.check-jacksmoney84.loan/web/, http://lucky-spot1.com/?u=9gzpte4&o=r90kmze&t=main7_6&c_id=bbf13e6e-b1c2-481e-af33-ac7509c42b49, http://lucky-spot1.com/cookie/js.cookie9.js, http://lucky-spot1.com/media/gambling/backbutton_gmb.js,

Подскажите где искать и как с этим бороться, а то гугл грозится бросить в блокировку меня:(

Comment: Весь список заразы

Comment: Обращайтесь к хостеру или тому у кого купили домен.

Comment: Поищи эту ссылку и удали ее

Comment: Как бы гугл теперь SO не заблокировал, а то тут теперь тоже "присутствуют следующие вредоносные ссылки"  ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Answer (score 0):

Ссылки указанные гуглом ведут на плохие сайты, их надо удалить. Ищите их либо в бд(если сайт на цмске), либо в коде самого сайта, это можно сделать с помощью нотпада++

Comment: Открывать каждый фал получается? А возможно быть такое что ссылка в base64?

Comment: @YuriVysochinsky В Notepad++ есть функция поиска по набору файлов(по всей папке, в каждом документе). Как бороться с basw64? Да очень просто, берешь и ищешь тот самый base64. Те, что сам писал оставляй(хотя я сомневаюсь что ты сам это используешь), а то, происхождение чего не знаешь удаляй. Если сайт на CMS написан, то это будет немного сложнее. Почитай как удалить вирус "мобильный редикт " с сайта, должно помочь